# как вернуть картинку из MySQL в pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сделать выбор аватарки и загрузки его в форме логина. Только не могу понять как конвертнуть массив BLOB в картинку.
Вот код

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Главный код

```
 private void photoLoad()
    {
        string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;" +
                        "port=3306;" +
                        "database=reg;" +
                        "username=root;" +
                        "password=Admin123";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        byte[] ImageByte = new byte[0];
        string query1 = "select image from reg.img_table where id= @id";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Properties.Settings.Default.idImg);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader row;
            row = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (row.Read())
            {
                ImageByte = (Byte[])(row["image"]); //error in debugging HERE
            }

            if (ImageByte != null)
            {
                // You need to convert it in bitmap to display the image
                roundPictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(ImageByte);
                roundPictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Img");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите вот эти вопрос-ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1354257/